# Tool for COM (Component Object Model) developers

Tags: windows-10

Does anyone know of a tool which lets you see which COM objects are registered and which lets you examine their GUIDS, CLSID, IID etc.?

Answer (score 1):

It has been a decade or so since I played with COM, so I can't be sure of details. However, free downloads of Python and PythonWin will give you most of what you want, at least. What's more, within the PythonWin environment you can use tooltip responses to explore interfaces effectively too.

[image: Python Object Browser in PythonWin]

Answer (score 0):

I think the Visual studio tool is [OLE/COM Object Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx/).
You can use it to:

- View registered objects.
- See the interfaces an object can handle.